# Having trouble building data frame when importing data with multiple lines of observation that should each be in one row

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

[This is the data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/cleveland.data)

[This is the data description](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/heart-disease.names)

Most people online only work with the processed file with 14 attributes but I'm trying to work with the unprocessed file with everything.

Building the data frame though, with each row representing a patient is a bit of an issue with me.

```
heart_data <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/cleveland.data",
             header = FALSE, sep = ' ', fill = TRUE)
```

This is about as far as I got, but that's only taking each row and throwing them in as separate elements whole piece along one column

Ideally, I want each element up to and including 'name' as one value per column for a single row each. Name being the final piece of information of each patient.

Comment: Read the help of the function `read.table`. When I open your data file, separators are not tabulation (\t) but space so `sep = " "`). However, each line seems not to have the same number of element ... `read.table` could throw an error as a table must have same number of column at each line

Comment: At the moment I'm using sep = ' ' and fill = TRUE in order to get around missing values of rows being different lengths

Comment: `heart_data <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/cleveland.data", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)` gives a dataframe with 8 columns

Comment: Yes, but I need all the individual values up to 'name'....so the end result should have 76 columns

Comment: you cannot use `read.table` then. try make your own read function for your file with `readLines` or `scan`. 
Reading each line of your file then concatenating string until name and separate each new string after should do the trick